# grid vs layout based widget toolkits

Tags: layout, grid, widget

grid only widget toolkits (like Cocoa Touch) vs layout based toolkits (like Swing or gtk+)

iOS Cocoa Touch, being only grid based, had to port all applications when the screen resolution was upgraded (iPhone4) or enlarged (iPad)

If you could choose what would you use?

Answer (score 0):

If I were designing for a platform where screen sizes could vary, I'd use a layout manager based toolkit. However if I could garuntee the same screen resolution and screen size, I'd choose to use a grid based toolkit, as it would mean I wouldn't need to think about all the logic that goes into making a layout manager based UI.